# VMware ESXi 5.5 loses connectivity after a while

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

My VMware ESXi 5.5 "Free Version" host keeps getting unreachable using VSphere Client.

I do not use a VSphere appliance, only the host itself.

Firewall is open (Port 902), there is no network issues

Virtual Machines works fine. They keep running !

I have to log in through SSH and type *services.sh restart*

Then everything goes back to normal. I looked at hostd logs and can't figure out what is the issue.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: What build are you running?  What hardware?  The more details you can provide the more we can help.  It seems like this is a common problem.  https://serverfault.com/questions/627200/cant-connect-to-esxi-5-x-with-vsphere-client-but-i-can-access-the-esxi-over-ssh?rq=1 https://serverfault.com/questions/196928/cant-connect-to-esxi-with-vsphere-client?rq=1  5.5 is

Comment: The first link is the exact same problem, i search but i didn't find this ! Thanks, that's weird because 2 other host are exactly the same and they don't have this issue, and also same build number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your ESXi installation. The software is meant to be patched and updated.

You are on build #1331820. That's basically saying that you haven't had any patches or bugfixes for nearly 4 years.

Please update your ESXi installation.

[image]

Comment: build number is 1331820

Comment: Update your ESXi installation.